# jQuery Run function on selector

Tags: jquery

I want to run a function based on the eq() selector:

```
$('div.entry-content div.one_fifth').eq(0, function(){
    $(this).css({background: 'url(../wp-content/themes/genesis/images/plant_hire.jpg) no-repeat center'});
    $(this).on('hover',function(){
     alert('Test');
    });
});
```

What is wrong with my syntax since the inside function is not working

Thanks

Comment: `.eq()` has no callback.

Comment: the .eq() method does not and should not accept a second parameter.

Comment: yeah...but you get the idea of what I am trying to do...This is best as I can explain it...

Comment: Add your HTML as well. It could be your html.

Comment: No we don't get it, as it makes no sense to have a callback on a completely syncronous method that returns the new collection anyway, and can be just chained with the methods you're trying to use inside the "callback" ? Also, there is no `on('hover')` (well, there is, but you should'nt use it)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select the zero index of your selector, change the css, and then attach the event handler for hover.

```
$('div.entry-content div.one_fifth')
    .eq(0)
    .css({background: 'url(../wp-content/themes/genesis/images/plant_hire.jpg) no-repeat center'})
    .on('hover',function(){
        alert('Test');
    });
```

EDIT, I cut and pasted what the OP originally had, I just assumed there were no syntax errors.

Comment: you have an extra `});`, otherwise looks fine.